# A Proposed Improvement to the Diet Coke and Mentos Experiment

Tags: home-experiment, nucleation

I am sure most of you are aware of the [Diet Coke and Mentos craze](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diet+coke+mentos+experiment) - put a few mentos in a bottle of diet coke and whoosh!

Equally, I am sure most of you are aware that this occurs because the gas is able to form bubbles in rapid succession at 'nucleation sites' - microscopic pits on the surface of the mentos.

It has been subsequently shown that using rock salt can extend the range of such rockets because of the high porosity, hence surface area, compared to mentos.

So, this got me thinking... could I used **activated carbon** instead of the salt/mentos?

It has a surface area of 500m2 per gram as measured by gas adsorption (funny that?) so to me it seems like it could have some pretty dramatic effects!

I haven't seen anything on the internet which indicated anyone has tried this?! Is there a reason why? Has anyone here done it? If not, it would be great if people could give it a go and post some results! I'm going to give this one ago myself and see what happens.

Comment: A tablet of activated carbon will float and thus will probably be quickly flushed out of the bottle. Mentos tabs sink and thus have a lasting effect.

Comment: Maybe you could attach the activated carbon to something denser to ensure it sinks?

Comment: I thought the same! I'm going to go buy some from a pet shop later today.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can :) How did it work out for you?

[image: It works!]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please explain your answer in more details.